# How to convert HttpWebRequest with POST method of a legacy program to HttpClient, using c#?

Tags: c#, httpclient, httpwebrequest

I have legacy code that uses HttpWebRequest and it works fine.  Microsoft suggests that we use HttpClient.  How can I modify it to use HttpClient, in c#?

```
string authText = "{   "AuthParams":{      "AuthToken":"TokenID",      "FirmID":"MSFT",      "SystemID":"Systems-Internal",      "Version":"1.0",      "UUID":"SystemsInternalAPIUser"   }}";
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://msft.com/api/busnWebService/xbox-games");
JObject data = JObject.Parse(authText);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(data);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
string responseText = streamReader?.ReadToEnd();

(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CompRoot>(responseText).Data)
.Select(t => new CompanyClass
{       
    Ticker = t.Ticker,      
}).ToList()
```

Comment: Which part of the "conversion" is giving you trouble? Have you tried first and how does you attempt look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I can not try the solution with your payload and endpoint, something like the following should solve the problem without testing it.

```
string authText = "{\"AuthParams\":{\"AuthToken\":\"TokenID\",\"FirmID\":\"MSFT\",\"SystemID\":\"Systems - Internal\",\"Version\":\"1.0\",\"UUID\":\"SystemsInternalAPIUser\"}}";
var content = new StringContent(authText, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var httpResponse = await client.PostAsync("http://msft.com/api/busnWebService/xbox-games", content);

string responseText = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

With `HttpClinet` you need to use `async Task` with `await`. I assume your mapping from the response should be the same. But you need to validate that.